# Clone some remote branches and push them to a new repository?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I have a `master`, a `development` and an `experimental` branch inside `old_repo`. How do I clone only `master` and `development` inside `new_repo`? Basically, I want to clone `old_repo` into `new_repo`, but without the `experimental` branch.

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm reusing an app and it has a lot of feature branches which I don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone from `old_repo`, fetch all other branches (`old_repo` is URL, `origin` the resulting alias)

```
git clone old_repo my_repo
cd my_repo
git fetch
```

Check out both branches to make sure we have a local ref of them

```
git checkout master
git checkout development
```

Add `new_repo` to remotes (`new_repo` is URL, `new` the alias), then only push `master` and `development`

```
git remote add new new_repo
git push new master development
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty repository

```
mkdir new_repo
cd new_repo
git init
```

Add the new old remote

```
git remote add old_repo url...
```

Fetch only the the relevant branches

```
git fetch old_repo master:refs/heads/master
git fetch old_repo development:refs/heads/development
```